# FILTER_VALIDATE_INT Returning error for value 0

Tags: php, filter

Expected value for the post is 0 OR 1 but when the value is zero it returns error

```
if(!($data['status'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'status',FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)))
{
  echo'Error';
}
else 
return true;
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with [tag:mysql] and [tag:database]?

Comment: Above Validation is before MySQL database insertion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` statement is implicitly converting the result of the call to `filter_input()` to a boolean and then testing that result.  In your case, the result is `0` which is implicitly converted to `FALSE`, so the test fails.

You need to explicitly test with an identity comparison against `FALSE`:

```
$data['status'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'status',FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($data['status'] === FALSE) ...
```

See [PHP type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is validating correctly and as per return value of `filter_input it is returning 0`

So you will get `$data['status'] = 0`

Then

`!($data['status'] = 0)` makes it to `1` that's why it print error message